# Best way to store data that will be used later (Vanilla-JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, scope

What is the best way to store data from let's say an AJAX call that I later on will use to present data? It is not always possible to use the data in the `success` function. Is `localStorage` considered a best practice?

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");
localStorage.getItem("username");
```

Ideally, I would use Angular or any other framework that handles this, but how should I do when I use vanilla JavaScript?

I know `window.dataVariable` should be avoided.

Comment: Please elaborate on `It is not always possible to use the data in the success function` - this sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: as often goes in programming, i think there's no universal best way for this. though localstorage is pretty common and it works, its *intended* use is to store information for longer periods of time. not to get around scope issues (like i think @mplungjan suspects)

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. localstorage is fine for storing key/value pairs of strings if you don't need to iterate over it. otherwise, you might be interested in [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: Thank you @n00dl3 for your suggestion. I will look in to IndexedDB

Comment: if you actually need it to persist when the user closes the browser and comes back to it, localstorage is a great choice, otherwise the global var should be fine

Comment: Ok. Thank you! @adamz4008

Comment: What do you mean by later? Like after reload of page? @AllramEst

Comment: I made a list of items that have edit buttons. But in between the first click and the actually update I have two steps that dont involve page-reload. I wanted to store the id of the item clicked somewhere until the actual AJAX update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `window.dataVariable` is discouraged is that it pollutes the global namespace with variables and could possibly be overridden elsewhere accidentally.

Storing it in localstorage would be a bad idea in my opinion as the serialization/deserialization would also need to be handled.

One simple way of handling this would be to create a custom namespace on the window object which will be the designated place to store data for future use.

Sample:

```
// Instantiate a namespace object before the AJAX runs
window._cache = {};


// Once AJAX call completes,
window._cache.dataVariable = data;
```

This will ensure your data is available for later without polluting the global namespace. (Although care must be taken to ensure the variables are added/modified only where it needs to be and in the correct order)

Comment: Just to clarify, using a custom namespace or not, it doesn’t make it safe from overwriting. In both cases they are still on be global scope.

Comment: Also I’m not sure what you mean by the “serialization/deserialization would need to be handled”?

Comment: @prasanthv correct, the variables can still be overwritten. Care must be taken to ensure the variables are written to only in the intended places and in the intended order. This just helps avoid unintentional clashes with other variables set by libraries/scripts etc. About the serialization/deserialization, localstorage accepts key value pairs where the value must be a string. So if we wanted to store an object, we would have to do something like `JSON.stringify(data)` before storage and `JSON.parse(value)` after retrieval from localstorage